# Why does Django's annotate seemingly modify the QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model, that (extremely simplified for the example) looks like this:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT) # details of Person don't really matter here
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False # the project has a shared db with another project, included because I don't know if it's relevant
        db_table = "cars"
```

I wish to have field called `driver_name` present on the Car model. My approach to that was to create a custom manager that annotates the queryset:

```py
class CarManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            driver_name = models.ExpressionWrapper(
                models.F("driver__surname") + ", " + models.F("driver__name"),
                output_field=models.TextField()
            )
        )
```

and then I set it as Car's manager, `objects = CarManager()`.

Now, by my understanding of `annotate`, this should just add a new field called `driver_name` that's a combination of each driver's name and surname, on each of the objects in the default queryset. I must be mistaken though, because there are 10 Car objects in the database, and running `Car.objects.all()` returns a queryset with a single object. That object happens to be the last Car in the database, but I don't know if that's relevant, since I don't have any way to check. If I remove the annotation from the custom manager, `.all()` correctly returns 10 objects.

What's wrong with my understanding of `annotate`?

Comment: I ran your code and I get all the objects back. The only thing I can think if is make sure `driver` is not nullable. (and i would still try to make that model managed because it makes life simpler, but you probably have your reasons). I would just consider making `driver_name` a `@property` on the `Car` model that returns `self.driver.surname + self.driver.name`

Comment: That use of + makes me nervous in expressionwrapper.  Wouldn't you be better off using `driver_name=Concat('driver__surname', Value(', '), 'driver__name', output_field=models.TextField())`